# Windows phone update listview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I created a Windows phone 8.1 application with a listview on Startpage.xaml. When I update listview values, I don't see the changes on the phone until I close and open the application again. I tried to update the listview when I clicked  the refresh button, but unsuccessfully. Anyone know how to update a listview when I click the refresh button?

How I fill in data in the listview:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    string str = ((ComboBoxItem)cbox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
    var response = await http.GetStringAsync("http://mywebpage.si/events/apis/facebook_events.php?city=" + str + "&user=" + uporabnik.user);
    var FSfeed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(response);

    Reviews.ItemsSource = FSfeed;

}
```

My class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Refresh button:

```
    private async void refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    string str = ((ComboBoxItem)cbox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
    var response = await http.GetStringAsync("http://mywebpage.si/events/apis/facebook_events.php?city=" + str + "&user=" + uporabnik.user);
    var FSfeed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(response);

    Reviews.ItemsSource = FSfeed;
    }
```

I also tried to refresh like this, but unsuccessfully:

```
    private async void refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PivotPage));
    }
```

Comment: Is the *ListView* filled correctly with the items for the first time? Maybe it's the problem witch *cached* response in *http.GetStringAsync* - in this case it would be refreshed, but with the same data.

Comment: Did you try debugging and checking that you are receiving a different set of data when refresh is clicked?

Comment: Have you tried switching your list view to an observable collection.  The Model View View Model Design pattern might be a helpful way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To update the view you need to update the binding to ItemSource:

```
List<Class1> mySource = new List<Class1>();
Binding binding = new Binding { Source = mySource };
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myListView, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```